# How to use Moq to test a method with no return value?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

This is my first question so please be kind! :)

What I am trying to do is write some tests for a manager class that during construction adds many new instances of a single item class to a list.  When the UpdateAllItems is called in this manager class the intention is to iterate the list and call Increment on each single item.

The manager class is my code, but the single item class is not so I can't modify it.

I use NUnit for a testing framework and am starting to work with Moq.  Because the manager class uses the single item class I would think I need to use a Moq so I am testing only the manager, not the single item.

How do I write tests for my UpdateAllItems method? (Technically I should be writing the tests first I know).

Here is a some sample code that gives a general idea of what I am working with...

```
public class SingleItem_CodeCantBeModified
{
    public int CurrentValue { get; private set; }

    public SingleItem_CodeCantBeModified(int startValue)
    {
        CurrentValue = startValue;
    }

    public void Increment()
    {
        CurrentValue++;
    }
}

public class SingleItemManager
{
    List<SingleItem_CodeCantBeModified> items = new List<SingleItem_CodeCantBeModified>();

    public SingleItemManager()
    {
        items.Add(new SingleItem_CodeCantBeModified(100));
        items.Add(new SingleItem_CodeCantBeModified(200));
    }

    public void UpdateAllItems()
    {
        items.ForEach(item => item.Increment());
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: How is this class useful? It creates an private list of counters and updates each item every time a method is called. There must be some change in the behavior of the object .. e.g. if UpdateAllItems doesn't work - what would be the change observed ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is, you can't. The method that `UpdateAllItems` calls (`Increment()`) is non-virtual, so you won't be able to mock it.

Your options, as I see it, are:

- Don't test `UpdateAllItems` at all. Its implementation is trivial, so this is an option to consider (though not ideal).
- Create real `SingleItem_CodeCantBeModified` instances in your test. Purists would say that you no longer have a *unit* test at this point, but it could still be a useful test.
- Add an `ISingleItem` interface, and an `SingleItemAdapter : ISingleItem` class that holds onto a reference to a `SingleItem_CodeCantBeModified` and forwards the calls. Then you can write `SingleItemManager` to operate on `ISingleItem`s, and you'll be free to pass in mock `ISingleItem`s in your tests. (Depending on how your system is set up, you might even be able to descend from `SingleItem_CodeCantBeModified`, implement the interface on your descendant, and use those objects instead of writing an adapter.)

That last option gives you the most options, but at the cost of some complexity. Choose the option that's best suited for what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Your Manager is too dependent on Item (in `List<Item>`). Can you extract list population into separate class to be able to mock it? e.g.:

```
public SingleItemManager()
{
    items.Add(ItemRepository.Get(100));
    items.Add(ItemRepository.Get(200));
}
```

Testing (some code omitted):

```
int i = 0;

var itemMock = new Mock<Item>();
itemMock.Setup(i => i.Increment()).Callback(() => i++);

var repositoryMock = new Moc<ItemRepository>();
repositoryMock.Setup(r => r.Get(It.IsAny<int>()).Returns(itemMock.Object);

var manager = new SingleItemManager();
manager.UpdateAllItems();

Assert.AreEqual(i, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As usual, you can add another level of indirection.

1. Create a wrapper class around `SingleItem_CodeCantBeModified`
2. Make this wrapper inherit `IItem` interface
3. Make `SingleItemManager` depend on `IItem` instead of `SingleItem_CodeCantBeModified`

OR

If `Increment` is a virtual method (I understand it isn't in your sample code, but just in case), use [partial mocking](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/09/the-joy-of-moq-partial-mocks/).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of hard-coding your additional concrete items, have the `SingleItem_CodeCantBeModified` implement an interface (or embed it in a wrapper which implements the interface) then pass in a (new) factory which will create these items.

In your test you will create a mock of the factory to pass in to your Manager class, then you can monitor what methods are called on that mocked object.

Although this would be more about testing the internals of the system, not the byproducts. What interface is the Manager implementing? If it's not proving itself externally, what results are you testing for?

Comment: SingleItem_ **CodeCantBeModified**

Comment: @riezebosch: If push comes to shove you can create a proxy object that implements an interfact and just passes through method calls. Its not quite the same thing as gettting the class to implement the interface but has the same effect.